# Поместить выбор из JList в JComoboBox

Tags: java, gui

Как можно поместить выбор из JList в JComoboBox, при чем, при каждом новом выборе- заменять старое значение-новым?

```
    int savedInd=jList1.getSelectedIndex(); //получили индекс
    String firstSelected= clients[savedInd].getSurname()+" "
                         +clients[savedInd].getName()+" "
                         +clients[savedInd].getMiddleName();
    if(comboBTemp.getModel().getSize()==0)comboBTemp.addItem(firstSelected);
    else //как можно осуществить замену?
```

Comment: Забыл упомянуть, код находится в событии jList1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первым приходит в голову - навесить слушателя событий на JList и по нему формировать данные в JComboBox'е.

Comment: какие нужно использовать методы jList1'а?

Comment: `jList.addListSelectionListener([ListSelectionHandler]);`

Comment: компилятор не понимает, что находится в скобках:
([ListSelectionHandler])
Что означает [ListSelectionHandler] ?

Comment: Это заглушка, говорящая, что на её место нужно поместить экземпляр класса ListSelectionHandler или класса расширяющго ListSelectionHandler.